# How to get the first date and last date of the previous month? (Java)

Tags: java, datetime, date

With today's date, I should get the first date and last date of the previous month. I am unable to come up with any logic.

For example, on passing `05/30/2012`, I should get `04/01/2012` and `04/30/2012`.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 36):

With [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
Date firstDateOfPreviousMonth = cal.getTime();

cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE)); // changed calendar to cal

Date lastDateOfPreviousMonth = cal.getTime();
```

**See**

- [ideone demo](http://ideone.com/ErCbI)

Comment: Do we ever need to use `getActualMinimum`? Or just assume it to always be 1?

Comment: for Date you can assume it to be 1 for Gregorian calendar, but there are multiple other fields as well, [check this out](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/GregorianCalendar.java#GregorianCalendar.0MIN_VALUES

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 10):

## tl;dr

```
YearMonth.now().minusMonths( 1 ).atDay( 1 )
```

…and…

```
YearMonth.now().minusMonths( 1 ).atEndOfMonth()
```

## Avoid j.u.Date

Avoid the bundled `java.util.Date` and `.Calendar` classes as they are notoriously troublesome. Instead, use the [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8 and later.

## java.time

The new [java.time framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8 ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)) has commands for this.

The aptly-named [`YearMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class represents a month of a year, without any specific day or time. From there we can ask for the first and last days of the month.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
YearMonth yearMonthNow = YearMonth.now( zoneId );
YearMonth yearMonthPrevious = yearMonthNow.minusMonths( 1 );
LocalDate firstOfMonth = yearMonthPrevious.atDay( 1 );
LocalDate lastOfMonth = yearMonthPrevious.atEndOfMonth();
```

## Joda-Time

**UPDATE:** The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

In [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.8, use the `LocalDate` class if you do not care about time-of-day.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ) );
LocalDate firstOfThisMonth = today.withDayOfMonth( 1 );
LocalDate firstOfLastMonth = firstOfThisMonth.minusMonths( 1 );
LocalDate endOfLastMonth = firstOfThisMonth.minusDays( 1 );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later
- Built-in.
- Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
- For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: See my [similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26321291/642706) to duplicate question for more discussion of this kind of code.

Comment: This is the recommended answer in 2019. I further recommend passing explicit time zone or offset to `now`, for example `YearMonth.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)` so it’s clear to the reader (and yourself) what you get.

Comment: Thanks for the info. And in case someone also meets the scenario, needs the format to be like "2023_07"(the default value will be "2023-07"), we can run the following:

println(YearMonth.now().minusMonths(2).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy_MM")).inspect())

Comment: @MadHatter Or `.replace( "-" , "_" )`

Comment: @BasilBourque Of course, that will do, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 4):

Use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

```
DateMidnight now = new DateMidnight();
DateMidnight beginningOfLastMonth = now.minusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1);
DateMidnight endOfLastMonth = now.withDayOfMonth(1).minusDays(1);
System.out.println(beginningOfLastMonth);
System.out.println(endOfLastMonth);
```

Output:

> 2012-04-01T00:00:00.000+02:00
>   2012-04-30T00:00:00.000+02:00

Explanation: a DateMidnight object is a Date Object with no time of day information, which seems like just what you need. If not, replace all occurrences of DateMidnight with DateTime in the above code.

Comment: The midnight classes and methods on Joda-Time have been deprecated. Use the method `withTimeAtStartOfDay`.

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3):

well you could create a calendar object, set the date to the first day of the current month (should be the first :P) and then you can do two operations: 
from your calendar object you can subtract a particular period of time, e.g. a month (this would give you the first date of the previous month, or a day, which would give you the last day of the previous month. i didn't try it but this would be my first steps.

Answer (score 2):

Would also like to add something to Jigar's answer. Use the `DateFormat` class to get the date in the format you specified in the question:

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
System.out.println(df.format(firstDateOfPreviousMonth));
System.out.println(df.format(lastDateOfPreviousMonth));
```

Output:

```
04/01/12
04/30/12
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static LocalDate getPreviousMonthStartDate() {

    return LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1).with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth());
}

public static LocalDate getPreviousMonthLastDate() {

    return LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1).with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
}
```

Using Java.Time is very easy to write code. java.time package has better design, more thread safe , lot of utility methods to support common operations and easy to handle timezone with Local and ZonedDate/Time APIs.

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: Upvoted because the code i good. Using java.time is a good idea. I very much agree with the review comment: It’s from the explanations that we all learn, so if you could provide some of that too? (You’ve got an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59335432/edit) link under the question.)

Answer (score 2):

//in the pattern you can use your desired format.

```
  DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
                LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
                String startDate = now.minusMonths(1).with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth()).format(format);
                String endDate = now.minusMonths(1).with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()).format(format);
```

Comment: I have tried multiple ways at last this fulfilled my requirement, for more date generators visit https://github.com/kreddy27/https---github.com-kreddy27-mythoughts

Answer (score 1):

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
    Date lastDateOfPreviousMonth = cal.getTime();
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    Date firstDateOfPreviousMonth = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public List customizeDate(String month, int year) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            String edates = null;
            String sdates = null;
            if (month.equals("JAN") || month.equals("MAR") ||
                month.equals("MAY") || month.equals("JUL") ||
                month.equals("AUG") || month.equals("OCT") ||
                month.equals("DEC")) {
                String s1 = "01";
                String s2 = "31";

                String sdate = s1 + "-" + month + "-" + year;
                System.out.println("Startdate" + sdate);
                SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                Date ed = sd.parse(sdate);
                sdates = sd.format(ed);
                System.out.println("ed" + ed + "------------" + sdates);
                String endDate = s2 + "-" + month + "-" + year;
                System.out.println("EndDate" + endDate);
                SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                Date d = s.parse(endDate);
                edates = s.format(d);
                System.out.println("d" + d + "------------" + edates);
            } else if (month.equals("APR") || month.equals("JUN") ||
                       month.equals("SEP") || month.equals("NOV")) {
                String s3 = "01";
                String s4 = "30";
                String sdate = s3 + "-" + month + "-" + year;
                System.out.println("Startdate" + sdate);
                SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                Date ed = sd.parse(sdate);
                sdates = sd.format(ed);
                System.out.println("ed" + ed + "------------" + sdates);
                String endDate = s4 + "-" + month + "-" + year;
                System.out.println("EndDate" + endDate);
                SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                Date d = s.parse(endDate);
                edates = s.format(d);
                System.out.println("d" + d + "------------" + edates);
            } else {
                if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Leap year");
                    if (month.equals("FEB")) {
                        String s5 = "01";
                        String s6 = "29";
                        String sdate = s5 + "-" + month + "-" + year;
                        System.out.println("Startdate" + sdate);
                        SimpleDateFormat sd =
                            new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                        Date ed = sd.parse(sdate);
                        sdates = sd.format(ed);
                        System.out.println("ed" + ed + "------------" +
                                           sdates);
                        String endDate = s6 + "-" + month + "-" + year;
                        System.out.println("EndDate" + endDate);
                        SimpleDateFormat s =
                            new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                        Date d = s.parse(endDate);
                        edates = s.format(d);
                        System.out.println("d" + d + "------------" + edates);
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Not a leap year");
                    String s7 = "01";
                    String s8 = "28";
                    String sdate = s7 + "-" + month + "-" + year;
                    System.out.println("Startdate" + sdate);
                    SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                    Date ed = sd.parse(sdate);
                    sdates = sd.format(ed);
                    System.out.println("ed" + ed + "------------" + sdates);
                    String endDate = s8 + "-" + month + "-" + year;
                    System.out.println("EndDate" + endDate);
                    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                    Date d = s.parse(endDate);
                    edates = s.format(d);
                    System.out.println("d" + d + "------------" + edates);
                }
            }
            list.add(edates);
            list.add(sdates);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Write some details to the answer rather posting only code .