# Get first and last date of the previous month

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the first date and last date of the previous month? (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828398/how-to-get-the-first-date-and-last-date-of-the-previous-month-java)

In java, how to get the first and last date of the previous month?

If I am not wrong the following code is to get the last date of the previous month.

```
Calendar aCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
aCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);    
aCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1) ;
System.out.println(new Timestamp(aCalendar.getTime().getTime()));
```

Correct me if I am wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: You say "*Correct me if I am wrong*". What do you see when you run this code?

Comment: @keppil: Thank you it helped and sorry I missed to view the link before I post this.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use [`getActualMaximum()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMaximum%28int%29)

```
Calendar aCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
// add -1 month to current month
aCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
// set DATE to 1, so first date of previous month
aCalendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);

Date firstDateOfPreviousMonth = aCalendar.getTime();

// set actual maximum date of previous month
aCalendar.set(Calendar.DATE,     aCalendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
//read it
Date lastDateOfPreviousMonth = aCalendar.getTime();
```

Comment: aleaCalendar.setCalendar.DATE, 1); this line has to be modified to aCalendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);

Answer (score 19):

```
Calendar aCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
aCalendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
aCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
Date lastDateOfPreviousMonth = aCalendar.getTime();
aCalendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
Date firstDateOfPreviousMonth = aCalendar.getTime();
```