# How to get next month start date and end date if current month is february?

Tags: java, date

```
   String febSt = "02/01/2014" ;
   String febEnd = "02/28/2014" ;
```

Above code is my input i need "03/01/2014" and "03/31/2014" as output .
 I tried more codes and used calendar functions also but no result.From this program i need next month start and end date .

```
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

    public class MonthCalculation {


        public void getNextMonth(String date) throws ParseException{


            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            Date dt = format.parse(date);


            Date begining, end;

            {
                Calendar calendar = getCalendarForNow(dt);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                setTimeToEndofDay(calendar);
                end = calendar.getTime();

                SimpleDateFormat endDt = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                String endStrDt = endDt.format(end);
                if(date != null && date.equalsIgnoreCase(endStrDt)){
                    System.out.println("Ending of the month");
                    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                    Date lastDate = calendar.getTime();
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                    String lastDateofNextMonth = sdf.format(lastDate);
                    System.out.println("Next Month :"+lastDateofNextMonth);

                    Calendar c = getCalendarForNow(new Date(lastDateofNextMonth));
                    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    setTimeToEndofDay(calendar);
                    end = calendar.getTime();

                    SimpleDateFormat sfd = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                    String lastDated = endDt.format(end);
                    System.out.println("Testing side :"+lastDated);

                }else if (findLeapYear(dt)){
                    Calendar calendar3 = getCalendarForNow(dt);
                    calendar3.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
                    Date ds = calendar3.getTime();
                    SimpleDateFormat dtft = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                    String dates = dtft.format(ds);
                    dtft.setLenient(false);
                    System.out.println("YEAR : "+dates);

                }else{
                                    SimpleDateFormat dtft = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                    Calendar calendar2 = getCalendarForNow(dt);
                    System.out.println(" Calendar time :->> " + dtft.format(calendar2.getTime()));
                    int curre_month = calendar2.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    int curre_day = calendar2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    int curre_year = calendar2.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                    Date dat = calendar2.getTime();
                    calendar2.add(Calendar.DATE, 31);
                    Date ds = calendar2.getTime();
                    String dates = dtft.format(ds);
                    dtft.setLenient(false);
                    System.out.println("OTHER DAYS : "+dates);

                }
            }

        }

        private static boolean findLeapYear(Date dt){
            boolean isLeapYr = false;
            int yr = dt.getYear();
            if ((yr%4 == 0 && yr%100!=0)){
                isLeapYr = true;
               }
            return isLeapYr;
        }

        private static Calendar getCalendarForNow(Date dt) {
            Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(dt);
            return calendar;
        }

        private static void setTimeToBeginningOfDay(Calendar calendar) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }

        private static void setTimeToEndofDay(Calendar calendar) {
            System.out.println("For feb calling");
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {

            try {
                String janSt = "01/01/2014" ;
                    String janEnd = "01/31/2014" ;

                    String febSt = "02/01/2014" ;
                    String febEnd = "02/28/2014" ;

                    String marSt = "03/01/2014" ;
                    String marEnd = "03/31/2014" ;

                    String aprilSt = "04/01/2014" ;
                    String aprilEnd = "04/30/2014" ;

                    String maySt = "05/01/2014" ;
                    String mayEnd = "05/31/2014" ;

                    String juneSt = "06/01/2014" ;
                    String juneEnd = "06/30/2014" ;

                    String julySt = "07/01/2014" ;
                    String julyEnd = "07/31/2014" ;

                    String augSt = "08/01/2014" ;
                    String augEnd = "08/31/2014" ;

                    String sepSt = "09/01/2014" ;
                    String sepEnd = "09/30/2014" ;

                    String octSt = "10/01/2014" ;
                    String octEnd = "10/31/2014" ;

                    String novSt = "11/01/2014" ;
                    String novEnd = "11/30/2014" ;

                    String deceSt = "12/01/2014" ;
                    String deceEnd = "12/31/2014" ;

                    String jan15St="01/01/2015";
                    String jan15End="01/31/2015";

                    String leapyr = "02/29/2016";
                    String notaleapyr = "02/28/2015";

                new MonthCalculation().getNextMonth(febSt);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
```

I tried more with sample inputs , for the months February ,april, june  nov start date are not working if i pass these dates as inputs it returns with 2nd of next month
    Suggest any idea to proceed further.I am struggling this code.
    Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your code that didnt work

Comment: I think the quickest is to find the first day of the month being March and add -1 day , but again that's a little hacky

Comment: Or Joda Time? That would definitely be better than using Date/Calendar.

Comment: I'd also *strongly* advise you to separate out your text conversion code from the date handling code. Currently they're mixed up all over the place - it would be much cleaner if you had a parse phase, a processing phase, and then a formatting phase. Then you could have a separate method for each, which didn't need to care about anything else.

Comment: If we add -1 day mean for march month start and end date if i pass then i wont get a next(April) months start and end date it displays wrong output.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();         
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
Date nextMonthFirstDay = calendar.getTime();
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
Date nextMonthLastDay = calendar.getTime();
```

Comment: The best solution with old `Calendar` stuff.

Comment: Great solution, thx!

Comment: I think it should zero the time to get the first moment of the day.

Answer (score 10):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( "02/14/2014" , DateTimeformatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" ) )
         .with( TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfNextMonth() )
```

…and…

```
LocalDate.parse( "02/14/2014" , DateTimeformatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" ) )
         .with( TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth() )
```

## java.time

The modern way is with the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) bundled with Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310).

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeformatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "02/14/2014" , f );
```

The `TemporalAdjuster` interface defines a way for implementations to manipulate date-time values. The `TemporalAdjusters` class provides several handy implementations.

```
LocalDate firstOfMonth = ld.with( TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth() );
LocalDate firstOfNextMonth = ld.with( TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfNextMonth() );
```

The Question asks for the first and last of the following month, March in this case. We have the first of next month, so we just need the end of that month.

```
LocalDate lastOfNextMonth = firstOfNextMonth.with( TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth() );
```

By the way, as discussed below, the best practice for defining a span of time is the Half-Open approach. That means a month is the first of the month and running up to, but *not* including, the first of the month after. In this approach we do not bother with determining the last day of the month.

## Joda-Time

UPDATE: The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Easy when using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library and its [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "MM/dd/yyyy" );
LocalDate localDate = formatter.parseLocalDate( "02/14/2014" ); 
LocalDate firstOfMonth = localDate.withDayOfMonth( 1 ); 
LocalDate nextMonth = localDate.plusMonths(1); // Use this for "half-open" range.
LocalDate endOfMonth = nextMonth.minusDays(1); // Use this for "fully-closed" range.
```

## Half-Open

Tip: Rather than focus on the last moment of a span of time, a better practice is to use the "Half-Open" approach.

In half-open, the beginning is inclusive and the ending is exclusive. So for "a month", we start with the first of the desired month and run up to, **but not including**, the first of the *next* month.

```
February 2014 = 2014-02-01/2014-03-01
```

## Span Of Time

Be aware that Joda-Time provides three handy classes for handling a span of time: [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html), [Period](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html), and [Duration](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html).

These classes work only with date-time objects ([`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class) rather than the date-only ([`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class) shown in code above.

While not directly relevant to your question, I suspect these span-of-time classes may be helpful.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

Something I quickly wrote for you - so could be cleaned up. Check if this helps:

```
    String string = "02/01/2014"; //assuming input
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Date dt = sdf .parse(string);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(dt);
    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);  //adding a month directly - gives the start of next month.
    String firstDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    System.out.println(firstDate);

    //get last day of the month - add month, substract a day.
    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
    String lastDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    System.out.println(lastDate);
```

Comment: Hi Vinay Rao , My input is if i pass month start and end date means it should return next month start and end-date respectively ,this what i wrote above the code .From your program it returns current month start and end date but i need next month start and enddate .

Comment: Sankar, that's what it does - it takes 1-Feb and returns 1-Mar and 31-Mar. That's what you need, right? I am adding a month.

Comment: Ok i agree this is for month shifting , in case if i shift one year means what to do .Suppose shifted year was leap year then i need that month Feb 28 .Eg:-Input 02/29/2016 , output -02/28/2017.Another one Input--- 02/28/2015  i need a output 02/29/2016 ,for these cases what to do ...?

Comment: This is applicable for all 12 months.If i pass Eg:-Input 02/21/2014 , output -02/22/2014 and Eg2:-Input 04/16/2015 , output -05/16/2015 respectively.

Comment: Okay, so your input need not be the 1st of every month. You need to polish your question. Anyway, you can use the Calendar class to your advantage. Force the day of month to the the last day of month. I'd probably reset day of month to 1, add the year, and then set the date to last day of month. Let me know if you want me to post the code.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I tried more,but i cant find the solution.My requirement is if i pass month start date, end-date or in-between days i want next month start date or end date or in-between days .It also applicable for years also .Suppose if that year is leap year means i for month February i want last date (29th-Feb).Just provide the code for that one.

Answer (score 2):

since it is hard to get in your code I have write some coe for you. please check it out..

```
Date today = new Date();  

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();  
calendar.setTime(today);  

calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);  
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);  
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);  

Date lastDayOfMonth = calendar.getTime();  

DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");  
System.out.println("Today            : " + sdf.format(today));  
System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + sdf.format(lastDayOfMonth));
```

Comment: niiraj874u,My input is if i pass month start and end date means it should return next month start and end-date respectively ,this what i wrote above the code .

Answer (score 2):

I see the question is old. But I used the [DateUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html) static methods *ceiling* and *truncate*. Came in pretty handy instead of using multiple lines of code.

```
Date today = new Date();

DateUtils.truncate(new Date(), Calendar.MONTH) // Thu Dec 01 00:00:00 EET 2016
DateUtils.ceiling(new Date(), Calendar.MONTH) // Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 EET 2017
```