# Java : Given date is within 12 months or not

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have a date string of the form `"07-AUG-13"`.

I want to know whether the given date is within a certain period from the current date or not.

```
bool 
isItWithin(int period){
    //check if "07-AUG-13" is within a "period" months from now
}
```

Comment: any effort from your side?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Hint: Use `java.util.Calendar` to do this.

Comment: I have so many approach on net but confused. People have used joda, util.calender etc. Can you help me using util.Calender

Comment: or another hint you could think of date in millis and do arithmetic on it to find if its within 3/6/9 months range.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get next month start date and end date if current month is february?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493196/how-to-get-next-month-start-date-and-end-date-if-current-month-is-february). And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10828398/642706) and many others.

Comment: I have seen this link and trying to understand the ans given by @Juvanis. But didn't get that. if ((year1 * 12 + month1) - (year2 * 12 + month2) > 6) logic

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Date month difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086396/java-date-month-difference)

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Calendar` class:

```
  public static boolean isWithinMonths(Date startDate, Date endDate, int months) {
    Calendar startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    startCalendar.setTime(startDate);
    Calendar endCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    endCalendar.setTime(endDate);

    startCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, months);

    return startCalendar.before(endCalendar);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 8 use the new time api.

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2004, Month.JANUARY, 1);
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2005, Month.JANUARY, 1);

long monthsInYear2 = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(startDate, endDate);
```

Comment: @vjs I think you'll find that's from java 8, but you could also use JodaTime

Comment: Yes you could use the JodaTime jar, which has similar functionality as above. Java 8 adopted date management as in JodaTime.

Comment: Flagging this question as duplicate of Java Date month difference

Answer (score -2):

i recommend you to use [Joda Time Library] instead of JDK<8 [Joda...]

or you can try this stuff:

```
long diff = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
long monthDiff=Math.ceil((diff / (60 * 60 * 24)));
```